# 4-bit number to decimal number

Tags: binary, octave

Juts like the title says: a code to convert a 4-bit number into a decimal equivalent number without using any fucntion from octave's library. Not a clue!

We consider the input a binary number (example: 0001, 1010) to decimal number as a output.

Comment: No. Actually it is homework =s

Answer (score 1):

One stupid way:  let the input be $n$.  I don't know octave, so consider this pseudo-code.  Usually constants in programming languages are in base $10$
If n=0, output "0"
If n=1, output "1"
etc

Presumably you need to output a string.

Another similar idea.  Define an array out as ["0","1","2" ,\dots "15"]
Print out(n)

Answer (score 0):

Recall what each location in the binary form represents: the locations of the 1's describe *which powers of two* make up the number. For a 4-bit number, the 4 locations represent $2^3$, $2^2$, $2^1$, and $2^0$, in that order (increasing powers of two from right to left). Thus in your example,

0001: $2^0 = 1$

1010: $2^3 + 2^1 = 8+2 = 10$

So, for the code, a simple way is to loop through the elements of the binary number, and if that element is 1, add it to your number,

```
x = [0 0 0 1];
n = length(x);
y = 0;
for i = 1:n
    if x(i)
        y = y + 2^(n-i);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I already did it but I can't fully understanding the part of the vector x= [0 0 0 1]. Let me explain, my questions is: Do i have to create another vector  "x=[...]" just to find another output in decimal number right? or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a binary number, x2, entered in decimal format, this should work:

x10=0;
for i=3:-1:0
d=floor(x2/10^i);
x2=x2-d*10^i;
x10=x10+d*2^i;
end

x10 will be the decimal representation you want.